# Kibana linking two independent events

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have ELK configured for collecting data offline, the log files look something like this :

```
Info 2015-08-15 09:33:37,522 User 3 connected
Info 2015-08-15 10:03:57,592 User 99 connected

Info 2015-08-15 11:42:37,522 User 99 disconnected 
Info 2015-08-15 11:49:12,108 User 3 disconnected
```

What I'm looking for is the average connection time on a time line.

I can't add more information to the messages, specifically i can't add the connection time to the disconnection message.

Comment: How are you loading up those logs into ES? With logstash?

Comment: Can you use a logstash filter? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're loading your ES with Logstash, you can use the [`aggregate`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html) filter in order to assemble discrete log lines that are correlated. The idea is to notice when a long-lasting event starts (i.e. User connected) and then end it when the `disconnected` event for the same user flies by: (note that your grok pattern might differ, but the principle is the same)

```
filter {
    grok {
        match => [ "message", "%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{WORD:entity} %{INT:userid} %{WORD:status}" ]
    }

    if [status] == "connected" {
        aggregate {
            task_id => "%{userid}"
            code => "map['started'] = event['timestamp']"
            map_action => "create"
        }
    }

    if [status] == "disconnected" {
        aggregate {
            task_id => "%{userid}"
            code => "event['duration'] = event['timestamp'] - map['started']"
            map_action => "update"
            end_of_task => true
            timeout => 86400000
        }
    }
}
```

You'll end up with and additional field called `duration` (in milliseconds) which you can then use to plot on Kibana for showing the average connection time.

Also note that I'm giving an arbitrary timeout of one day, which might or might not suit your case. Feel free to play around.

Comment: Yeay :) i think this will work just right! I have about a week or so before i can test it, might be more. Once it's working i'll mark the answer as accepted!

Thanks alot!

Comment: I'm glad if that helps. Definitely keep us posted when you get the time!

Comment: Were you able to try this out?

Answer (score 1):

One of the downsides of Elasticsearch is that it isn't a relational database - so cross referencing is much more limited. There's a nice blog post about it: [Managing Relations inside Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch)

But the long and short of it is - there isn't a way to query this sort of thing directly. Each event is a discrete document within your index, and there isn't any sort of cross reference.

So you have to do it the hard way. At the simplest level - that's query all the connect events, query all the disconnect events, and correlate them yourself with a scripting language.

You can make this slightly easier by pre-filtering your logs with a `grok` filter to add fields to your database.

```
if [type] == "syslog" and [message] =~ /connected/ {
    grok { 
        match => [ "message", "User %{POSINT:userid} %{WORD:conn}" ]
    }
}
```

Which will add a `userid` and `conn` field (containing "connected" or "disconnected").

But you will still have to manually correlate the queries with a database fetch using your favourite scripting language (so could just do the 'search and filter' in the script).