# Linking log file records for start and end of event in Kibana

Tags: join, elasticsearch, kibana

I'm using Kibana to provide output from our logfiles.  I've been trying to find a way to link the log records for the start and end of an event, specifically I'd like to identify start records that are over a certain age limit which don't have a matching end record. The records will each hold an event ID which can be used to find the matching records.
I thought that the Elasticsearch parent-child relationship or the terms lookup mechanism would do what I need but in both cases it looks like I need to create the relationship when indexing the records.  Is there another way of doing this or have I missed something?

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34652075/kibana-linking-two-independent-events

Comment: Thanks Val, that would do pretty much what I need.  Unfortunately we are using Cloudwatch rather than Logstash, but, armed with a solution, I'll now look at how to do it in Cloudwatch.