# Logstash - one event per logile

Tags: logstash, multiline

We want to introduce a log management tool. One of the possible candidates is the ELK stack.

I looked into the manual and it says that logstash is primary for logs which are continuously written and one event per line. Unfortunately we have to deal with logs where it would we one event per logfile. For example:

```
************************************************************
Protokollstart: XX.XX.XXXX XX:XX:XX
SessionID: XXXXX - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - XXXX
Kommentar: DASY


DASY-Batchlauf für Aufgaben bis  XX.XX.XXXX XX:XX:XX

Sachbearbeiter: XXXX
ACHTUNG: Echtlauf - Daten gespeichert

Selektierte Gläubiger - Achtung: keine Aufgaben auf Partnerakten betrachtet
   XX - XXXXX
   XX - XXXXX
   XX - XXXXX


nur Aufgaben zum XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX betrachtet
nur Aufgaben zur Wiedervorlage XXXX betrachtet

************************************************************
Startzeit        : XX.XX.XXXX XX:XX:XX
************************************************************

Es liegen keine Aufgaben zur Bearbeitung an.

insgesamt bearbeitete Anzahl Aufgaben: 0

************************************************************
Ende des DASY-Batchlauf für Aufgaben: XX.XX.XXXX XX:XX:XX

Statistik:
    Warnungen: 0

Protokollende: XX.XX.XXXX XX:XX:XX
************************************************************
```

I know that there is a multiline plugin / codec, but we some problems to deal with.

1. There has to be an indicator whether the file is still written or finished, because there can occur large gaps between the writing of the file. The indicator should always be

   ```
    Protokollende: XX.XX.XXXX XX:XX:XX
   ```
2. The writing of the files can last multiple hours (we once had a workload running for 48 hours) and the event mustn't trigger until the in 1. defined indicator is reached.

Is there any way to implement these requirements with standard functionality?
I hope I described my problem the problem well enough. If there are any questions please let me know :)

Comment: You might want to take a look to the [aggregate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html) filter and this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34652075/kibana-linking-two-independent-events/34652594). But I think logstash is a poor fit for your kind of logs. The aggregate filter might help you to regroup together the lines according to XX.XX.XXXX XX:XX:XX.

Comment: Or you can use the multiline with `multiline {
    pattern => "Protokollende"
    negate => true
    what => "previous"
  }` It will regroup all the lines not beginning with Protokollende