# Combine multiple log lines in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, kibana, fluentd

In kibana, is it possible to combine multiple log lines based on some key?

For example, if I log an http request and response separately. In the request I log the url, and in the response I log the status code.
In each log line I also log a request id, which is used to "connect" the two log lines.

Based on this data, is it possible to create a visualization that shows urls for a specific status code?

Comment: I'd say this isn't a duplicate

Comment: ...for sure, although that question may hold the correct approach, the fact that the answer to that question is an answer to this question does not make this a clear dupe

Comment: I think that the other question also answers my question, so I marked it as duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that this is a case of an XY Problem
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Kibana is not the part of the ELK stack you want doing heavy lifting of dynamically analyzing different events to derive information from them. I'm fairly certain its not possible, and even if it technically is possible, its not what you should do.

You have a couple paths you could take:

- Change your logging format to include the data you want to be tied together (response logs include URL)
- Use Logstash to link the two data together, there are numerous ways to achieve this, but in this case I would point you towards the proposed dupe and the use of an aggregate filter to combine the request and response logs into one event within Logstash. Then the two data points you want to visualize are part of the same event and easy to work with in Kibana [Kibana linking two independent events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34652075/kibana-linking-two-independent-events)